# User co_p already has more than 'max_user_connections' active connections

Tags: php, mysql

I have a PHP Code to insert some information from a large text file
in the beginning of the file i have this code:

```
<?php
$host = "localhost";
$username = "user";
$password = "pass";
$db = "dbname";

mysql_connect($host,$username,$password) or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($db) or die(mysql_error());
mysql_close;

set_time_limit(0);

$fh = fopen("file.txt", "r");
while ($row = fgets($fh)) {
//// CODE ....
   mysql_query("INSERT IGNORE INTO `TABLE` VALUES (NULL, '$ETC', '$ETC', '$ETC')"); 
}
    fclose($fh);
?>
```

but after some iserts i got this error :

> Warning: mysql_connect(): User co_p already has more than 'max_user_connections' active connections in /home/username/public_html/file.php on line 7
>   User co_p already has more than 'max_user_connections' active connections

any solution for this problem ?

- I'm the OWNER of the SERVER !

Comment: FYI, [you shouldn't use `mysql_*` functions in new code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [red box](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which one is best for you.

Comment: Sounds like you either need to optimize your resource management or find a host with less restrictive rules around open connections.

Comment: @JohnConde im the owner of the server

Comment: Are you connecting before attempting each query? Show more code

Comment: @RiggsFolly code edited

Comment: Since you own the server have you considered opening up the MySQL config files and editing `max_user_connections`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mysql_close;
```

should be generating an error.

This command should be

```
mysql_close();
```

> Add [error reporting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-to-get-useful-error-messages-in-php/845025#845025) to the
>   top of your file(s) *while testing* right after your opening PHP tag for example
>   `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` to see if it yields anything.
>
> But I have to ask, why are you connecting to the database and then closing the connection straight after?

#### After more code added.

As you are actually trying to access the database, you dont want to do a `mysql_close();` where you have coded it.

But I have to add:

> Every time you use [the `mysql_`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)
>    database extension in new code
>    **[this happens](https://media.giphy.com/media/kg9t6wEQKV7u8/giphy.gif)**
>    it is deprecated and has been for years and is gone for ever in PHP7.
>   If you are just learning PHP, spend your energies learning the `PDO` or `mysqli` database extensions and prepared statements.
>   [Start here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Comment: im new in php and mysql so i will start learning PDO and MSQLi soon,

so should i remove the mysql_close(); from the code ?

Comment: Yes, at least remove the ones you have directly after the connection run before you use the connection

Answer (score 0):

Try to close mysql connection:

```
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');
....
mysql_close($link);
```